# "close question" button on the waffle bar doesn't work on a small screen

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, responsive-design, waffle-bar

For some flags on questions, moderators have the option to handle the flag by closing the question. If you visit a post with a pending flag, the flag shows up in a bar at the bottom of the screen, known as a [waffle bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=2315343#2315343) (mod-only link). However, with the responsive design, the "close question" button doesn't seem to do anything:

[image: Screenshot of a flagged post on mobile. The "Close question" button is colored to indicate it has been pressed, but the close dialog is nowhere to be found.]

Particularly for an "excessively long post" like the one screenshotted above, this is rather inconvenient to then have to find the regular close interface when in theory you can just use the big button that appears as soon as you visit the post. While not a major bug, ideally this button would work as intended even on a small screen.